# Only entering first Thread, cannot enter following threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to process data using several threads, but for the moment only the first thread runs, then it completely stops.

I'm trying to print out the names of the Threads but I am only entering the first Thread. It just stops even though the program keeps running. It goes to the `synchpoint.await()` then stops.

```
public class Solver {
  final int N;
  final float[][] data;
  final CyclicBarrier barrier;

class Worker implements Runnable {
    public int myRow;
    String name;
    public CyclicBarrier synchPoint;

    Worker(CyclicBarrier barrier, int row, String name) {
        myRow = row;
        this.name = name;
        this.synchPoint = barrier;
        this.run();
    }

    public void run() {
            System.out.println("Name: " + name);
            processRow(myRow);
            mergeRows();

            try {
                System.out.print("In SynchPoint");
                synchPoint.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                return;
            } catch (BrokenBarrierException ex) {
                return;
            }
    }
}

public void processRow(int numRow){
    System.out.println("In Process Row");
}

public void mergeRows(){
    System.out.println("In merge Row");
}

public Solver(float[][] matrix) {
    data = matrix;
    N = matrix.length;
    System.out.println("N: " + N);
    Runnable barrierAction =
            new Runnable() { public void run() { mergeRows(); }};
    barrier = new CyclicBarrier(N, barrierAction);

    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        String myName = "Worker-" + i;
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Worker(barrier, i, myName));
        threads.add(thread);
        thread.start();
        System.out.println("In loop, i is: " + i);
    }

    // wait until done
    for (Thread thread : threads)
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }

  public static void doWork(){
      float[][] matrix2 = new float[6][2000];
      Solver solve = new Solver(matrix2);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Solver.doWork();
  }
}
```

**Output:**

> N: 5
>   Name: Worker-0
>   In Process Row
>   Row is: 0
>   Data Length: 5
>   In merge Row
>   In merge Row
>   In SynchPoint

Comment: I assume this is based on the sample from the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html).

Comment: What's your full output?

Comment: Yes it is based on the sample.

Comment: output:N: 5
Name: Worker-0
In Process Row
Row is: 0
Data Length: 5
In merge Row
In merge Row
In SynchPoint

Comment: I suspect thread.join(); must be this.join() for main thread to wait other threads to finish. am I right?

Comment: @JeannPierre It's hard to read the output on one line. Please [update](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41049148/edit) your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a nasty habit of making your constructors do work other than initializing an instance.  It is not ultimately harmful that `Solver`'s constructor does this, but the fact that `Solver.Worker`'s invokes the instance's `run()` method is the source of your problem.

You run the `Worker` constructor in the application's main thread.  That constructor invokes `run()`, which suspends the thread when it reaches `synchPoint.await()`.  The thread would resume when sufficient other threads reach that point, but none ever will, because the one thread that did is the one that would have created and started the others, and it cannot proceed.

Remove the `this.run()` from `Worker`'s constructor and you should get a lot further.

Comment: The nasty habit is likely inspired by the [javadoc sample](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html).

Comment: That may very well be, @shmosel, but that doesn't make it any less nasty.  I hope what the OP takes from my somewhat raw characterization is a strong admonition not to do that.  If he also comes away thinking I'm a jerk -- well, I can live with that.  Jerkophobes should not frequent the Internet.